# Comparing objects based on their MD5

Tags: javascript, php, object, md5

I have a huge object on client side and a same object on the server side. To ensure that the two objects are same at a particular point of time, will comparing the `MD5` of two objects ensure, that they are equal? If yes, is there a better way to achieve this?

I do not want to send the whole object to the server for comparison.

Comment: Are you trying to update password only when it is different ?

Comment: It is a good way. I also use it to compare my databases b/w server and android client. Just generate md5 and send it to client via json format.